# dracut -f shows "Failed to find module" and nvme error message

Tags: centos, dracut

Running `dracut -f <pathToInitRamFs> <kernelVersion>` to add some custom drivers to the initramfs shows an error message from the `nvme` command.

In addition, it fails to copy those custom drivers into the initramfs saying

```
dracut-install: Failed to find module 'DtPcie' /lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64//kernel/drivers/misc/DtPcie.ko
```

Even though the file does exist in the root filesystem tree:

```
# ls -l /lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64//kernel/drivers/misc/Dta.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 56015744 Jul  6 13:03 /lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64//kernel/drivers/misc/Dta.ko
```

And `lsinitrd` confirms the initramfs does not contain the Dta.ko driver (and in fact does not contain the entire `drivers/misc` subtree:

```
# lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64.img | grep Dta
# (nothing)
# lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64.img | grep misc
# (nothing)
```

**Original error message**

```
dracut -f /boot/initramfs-4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64.img 4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64
nvme-1.9.dirty
usage: nvme <command> [<device>] [<args>]

The '<device>' may be either an NVMe character device (ex: /dev/nvme0) or an
nvme block device (ex: /dev/nvme0n1).

The following are all implemented sub-commands:
  list                  List all NVMe devices and namespaces on machine
  list-subsys           List nvme subsystems
  id-ctrl               Send NVMe Identify Controller
  etc etc etc

See 'nvme <plugin> help' for more information on a plugin

dracut-install: Failed to find module 'DtPcie' /lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64//kernel/drivers/misc/DtPcie.ko
dracut-install: Failed to find module 'Dta' /lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64//kernel/drivers/misc/Dta.ko
dracut-install: Failed to find module 'Dtu' /lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64//kernel/drivers/misc/Dtu.ko
dracut-install: Failed to find module 'LXV4L2D_PL330B' /lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64//kernel/drivers/misc/LXV4L2D_PL330B.ko
```

This is the same output as if you type `nvme` by itself with any of the required arguments.

Other than rebuilding the initramfs with the command above I'm not doing anything with `dracut`.  But this error message is coming out.

I need those modules in the initramfs and I have not seen this dracut error before.  How would I resolve it?

System Info: Centos 8.1

```
# uname -a
Linux 4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 4 21:51:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# yum list installed | grep dracut
dracut.x86_64                        049-27.git20190906.el8                 @anaconda
dracut-config-rescue.x86_64          049-27.git20190906.el8                 @anaconda
dracut-network.x86_64                049-27.git20190906.el8                 @anaconda
dracut-squash.x86_64                 049-27.git20190906.el8                 @anaconda
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to include the missing modules by manually specifying them in a dracut config file at `/etc/dracut.conf.d/myModules.conf`

```
add_drivers+="Dta Dtu DtPcie"
```

(Do not put a space around the += )

Also, make sure you run `depmod -a` before using dracut to rebuild the initramfs.

This does not fix the error from the `nvme` command.